# javac junit gives "error: package org.junit does not exist"

Tags: java, junit, makefile, javac

I'm trying to use JUnit in a makefile but I can't get it to work.

My folder structure is as follows (makefile is in myProject):

```
myProject
|--bin
|--main
    |--org
        |--myPackage
|--test
    |--org
    |   |--myPackage
    |
    |--lib
```

where /main contains main files, /test contains test files and /lib contains `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and `junit-4.12.jar`

My makefile is as follows:

```
JAVAC = javac
JVM = java
JAVADOC = javadoc
MKBIN = mkdir -p bin

JAVAC_FLAGS = -g -d bin/
JAVAC_CP = -cp

SRC = main/
SRCTEST = test/
LIB = lib/*.jar

PACKAGE = org/myPackage/*.java
TARGET = bin

MAIN = org.myPackage.Main

.SUFFIXES : .class .java

all: 
    $(MKBIN) | $(JAVAC) $(JAVAC_FLAGS) $(SRC)$(PACKAGE)

test:
    $(MKBIN) | $(JAVAC) $(JAVAC_CP) $(LIB) $(SRCTEST)$(PACKAGE)

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET)

run:
    $(JVM) $(JAVAC_CP) $(TARGET) $(MAIN)

.PHONY: all test clean
```

When I'm running `make test` I get the following:

```
~/myProject | 18:07:29>make test
mkdir -p bin | javac -cp lib/*.jar test/org/myPackage/*.java
test/org/myPackage/MyClass.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

...
```

In Eclipse the tests work perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by looking at your folder structure it seems `lib` is inside `test` folder, if it is then i think your `$(LIB)` location needs to be changed

Comment: Why are you piping the (non-existent) output from `mkdir` into `javac? You should probably quote the `'lib/*.jar'` argument to avoid the shell expanding it too.

Comment: @SajanChandran Thanks, fixed.

I have edited my OP. Still get the same error.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, fixed and fixed.

I have edited my OP. Still get the same error.

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/you-need-no-maven-to-run-junit-tests/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

**EDIT FOUND THE ANSWER**

Ok, so I read some more and made some changes.

**First in my structure:**

```
|--bin
|--src
    |--main
    |   |--java
    |       |--myPackage
    |--test
        |--java
        |   |--myPackage
        |--lib
```

from [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

**And my new makefile:**

```
JAVAC = javac
JVM = java
JAVADOC = javadoc
MKBIN = mkdir -p bin

JAVAC_FLAGS = -g -d 'bin/'
JAVAC_CP = -cp

MAINSRC = src/main/java/
TESTSRC = src/test/java/
LIB = 'src/test/lib/*:src/main/java'

PKGSRC = myPackage/
TARGET = bin

MAIN = myPackage.Main

MAINTEST = myPackage.MainTest

.SUFFIXES : .class .java

all: 
    $(MKBIN)
    $(JAVAC) $(JAVAC_FLAGS) $(MAINSRC)$(PKGSRC)*

test:
    $(JAVAC) $(JAVAC_FLAGS) $(JAVAC_CP) $(LIB) $(TESTSRC)$(PKGSRC)*

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET)

run:
    $(JVM) $(JAVAC_CP) $(TARGET) $(MAIN)

run_test: 
    $(JVM) $(JAVAC_CP) $(TARGET) $(MAINTEST)

.PHONY: all test clean run run_test
```

**So the changes are:**

```
LIB = 'src/test/lib/*:src/main/java'
```

- Quotes around the classpath
- * instead of *.jar
- Classpath to main
- Classpath to class files should not include the *
- Multiple files are separated width ':' in Linux and ';' in Windows

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath).

```
JAVAC_FLAGS = -g -d 'bin/'
```

I forgot to include `$(JAVAC_FLAGS)` to `test` so that it didn't target the right folder (root/ instead of bin/).

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Thank you for not only answering your own question but providing a great level of detail! Its much appreciated!

Comment: You my friend have saved the day and taught me something. <3 <3 <3